# Twillio - Findme Twimlet

Tags: twilio

**Goal:**
I am attempting to create a python script that does a round robin call in the event the script has been executed.

**Purpose:**
This script is for a security company, we are attempting to reach members of a security team after hours. The script needs to be able to continue calling until confirmation.

I am very confused on how the FindMe twimlet is supposed to be executed. Can some one show me an example of how Twimlets are supposed work? Even some front to back documentation would be great. I've combed the internet the last week on the issue.

Side note:
I have submitted a ticket to their internal team, but I have no heard back for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander, the Findme Twimlet URL is associated with a Twilio phone number. When the Twilio phone number is called, it uses the FindMe Twimlet as its Voice URL which then kicks off the FindMe sequence.